# How to avoid laravel time and date change cheating

Tags: laravel, datetime

how to avoid fraud when someone tries to change the date on their device, but the date entered into the database remains the date that matches the database, to avoid fraud

please help me solve this problem, because I am learning to make a website-based application

Comment: Use the datetime of the server and not the client. I would recommend using Carbon for handling time and dates. https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/

Comment: if you want to avoid fraud about date or other, you should manage it on server side .

Comment: can you give me an example code and its use

Comment: how to implement it? I now only use Laravel and phpmyadmin only uses Laragon

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, you can get the good datetime by using:

```
date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

This should give the server datetime

Comment: Yes, I use that method too. but earlier I tried the application that I made and changed the date and time on my device, but the data captured according to the date that I changed on my device

Comment: Your server is running on the same device ?

Comment: Yes sir, because I just tried it

Comment: Haven't used another device yet

Comment: if that's case, it normal because the time of the device will be the server time.

Comment: oh, okay, thank you for the information and help, sir, I'll try again later on a different device with the server

Comment: Do you have a way so that the Laravel web base application can block or find out if a user is using a fake GPS

Comment: Not really. you can open a new question to ask it after validate the aswer of this question if it solved your problem.

Comment: how to validate if this question is solved? I'm new to this platform

Comment: https://ibb.co/9bPd2s7

Comment: open the link above to see how to do it.

Comment: `data()` looks like a typo though